# systemd - how to prevent service start if MAC address changes

Tags: systemd, docker

I have a Linux (Debian 10) server which runs a number of Docker containers, on Linode.

I have configured the Docker containers to restart unless stopped, so if the server has to be restarted, all the containers come up successfully.

I want to put Disaster Recovery (DR) testing in place, which involves taking the previous nights backup and restoring it to a new Linode instance.

Unfortunately, if it starts automatically, it will connect to my Postgres backup (pgbackrest), with possibly bad results (two primary clusters writing to the backup).

I want the DR server to not start docker (systemd) if the machine is changed (I assume I can detect this from the MAC Address, but other suggestions helpful).

How should I configure systemd (docker.service) to not start if the underlying machine changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple.

I copied docker.service from /lib/systemd/system to /etc/systemd/system

I added a conditional to the [Unit] section
ConditionHost=machine-id

where machine-id is retrieved from /etc/machine-id